# Bash script to run python script in virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, bash, virtualenv

I'm creating PHP application which need to run python script. I must use virtualenv. In project catalog i've created `env` directory and inside created virtual env named `python`. In another catalog i've put script i'd like to run and this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

app="$(pwd)/../"
pythonEnv="${app}env/python/"
source ${pythonEnv}"bin/activate"
"${pythonEnv}bin/python" "${app}scripts/script.py arg1 arg2"
```

But when i run this script (using terminal so far) i got this error:

```
/var/www/project/scripts/../env/python/bin/python: can't open file '/var/www/project/scripts/../scripts/script.py arg1 arg2': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Of course there is script.py in scripts directory and has right access permissions:

```
-rwxrwxr-x
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the directory. I assume directory is not right.. check where you put your script.

Comment: @orvi I was copying path from error and it's work, so directories are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading your error message, it appears that the interpreter thinks that the file is `/var/www/project/scripts/../scripts/script.py arg1 arg2` and not simply `/var/www/project/scripts/../scripts/script.py`. You should separate `arg1` and `arg2` from the file name.

Also, I think you can just write `python` instead of `"${pythonEnv}bin/python"` once you activated your virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

Due to your quoting, you are trying to call `"${app}scripts/script.py arg1 arg2"` as the script name - which does not exist. You can change your script to fix it:

```
${pythonEnv}bin/python ${app}scripts/script.py arg1 arg2
```

Adjust your quoting as needed, but keep it specific. For example, if you need to quote your `pythonEnv` variable do `"${pythonEnv}"`.